# consumer receives no message from Kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am using docker-compose.yml to set up multi-layer web app.

batch:

```
image: tp33/django
container_name: batch
links:
  - kafka:kafka
  - es:es
depends_on:
  - kafka
  - es
volumes:
  - ./batch_layer:/app
networks:
  - mynet
command: bash -c "cd /app && python consumer.py"
```

kafka:

```
image: spotify/kafka
container_name: kafka
environment:
  ADVERTISED_HOST: kafka
  ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
hostname: kafka
networks:
  - mynet
```

The batch layer is used as the consumer in Kafka, but it doesn't receive any message from queue. If I use "docker run -it --name batch --link kafka:kafka --link es:es --network=mynet tp33/django" instead of docker-compose to set up batch layer, the consumer can receive messages.

Could anyone figure out the difference?

Comment: Note: the Spotify image is no longer maintained and is using an old Kafka version

Comment: The primary difference is that you're hard coding the command in the compose file and you're not using interactive mode compared to `run -it`, but without your Python code, it's hard to really say since this isn't a [mcve]

Comment: did you do `docker-compose run` or `docker-compose up`?

Comment: I am using docker-compose up. I just fixed the problem by putting the KafkaConsumer() in try-except block and looping until successfully connecting to kafka from batch layer. But I still cannot figure out the difference

Comment: One thing that you can do is to make sure that kafka is actually fully running before start the command on the batch. You can see an example here https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ that waits for postgresql to be running first